# Run Android app in background without user interaction

Tags: java, android

I have an android app which keeps updating logs every 5 minutes.

I used **Alarm Manager** to achieve this.

But the app kept opening and closing automatically.

Is there any way to do this in background??

Comment: use service for that

Comment: Yes, as Android said, just use a `Service`. The whole idea with `Application`s is that they are visible.

Comment: just create background service .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use android Services for this task.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have to user `Service: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Next, you can start your program in background on BOOT event:

```
public class BootReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, LogService.class);
     context.startService(myIntent);
    }
```

Declare theese in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

  <!-- Declaring broadcast receiver for BOOT_COMPLETED event -->
        <receiver android:name=".BootReciever" android:enabled="true" android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```